# War Thunder Not Working! (Mac OS X)

Tags: war-thunder

for some reason my War Thunder won't work. I'm on Mac OSX, when i press play it says, "aces cannot be opened because of a problem."              (solved)

Comment: What Apple device are you trying to run it on? Edit your question to include the model and year.

Comment: I dont know how to find those. @Nzall

Comment: @RacingEcho Try these: https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201300

Answer (score 2):

Never mind everyone. After a long time of searching I found out that they ended mac support.

Comment: Hi RacingEcho, that's a shame. Can you link the source of this info to make it easier for others to confirm this?